# data and control path

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

While designing a digital system, do we always have to partition Data paths and the control units?

If not, what could be the situations where we really don't have to bother about the partitioning of these modules?

Thanks.

Comment: It's your design. You can make it as messy as you wish, without any logical separation. But then you will have to deal with it.

Comment: Your question will make more sense to us if you explain why you are asking the question, maybe with some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snarky comments aside, the answer to your question is no, you don't always have to separate them. It really depends on the nature of the function that the module implements and how complex the datapath and the control logic are.

Sometimes, with simple functions, it makes sense to do everything in a single process (e.g., `always` block in Verilog) within a module. As long as you can easily see all of the context for everything that's going on, this requires the least amount of source code and the smallest number of things that someone reading the code needs to memorize.

Other times, it makes sense to do them as separate processes within a single module.

And if either the control or datapath is very complex, it may make sense to implement them as separate modules, perhaps even with submodules internally. There are no hard-and-fast rules here.

As with any source code, keep in mind that you or someone else will have to read and understand it someday, and you want to make that as free from misunderstandings as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you MUST have SOME way of distinguishing between DATA and CONTROL information. Otherwise you don't have an operational system.  Many systems separate data and control PHYSICALLY, often for speed purposes. For example most higher-end CPU chips have separate DATA, ADDRESS, and CONTROL (and even I/O) paths.

And other communication protocols (like USB or Thunderbolt or SATA) share the same physical path for both data and control. And typically also sharing the same path for communication in BOTH directions. But they indentify blocks of information as data or control (or in some cases part of both).